# PHP - Check if an array value is in another array

Tags: php

So I have two arrays:

```
$gated_categories
array(2) { [0]=> int(3511) [1]=> int(3510) }
```

and

```
$category_id
array(3) { [0]=> int(3518) [1]=> int(3511) [2]=> int(3502) }
```

As you can see above, both arrays contain `3511`

So if `$gated_categories` contains a value which is is `$category_id`

I want this to return `true`, else `false`

I have tried with this:

```
$is_gated = !array_diff($gated_categories, $category_id);
```

But this is returning false, any ideas?

Comment: Use a nested for loop. Iterate through them and check when  is `$i` the same

Comment: `array_diff` returns the difference between two arrays, but you are negating the obtained result, that's why you are obtaining a boolean value. Use `array_intersect` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_diff()` does the opposite of what you want. It returns an array with the values of the first array that are **not** present in the other array(s).

You need `array_intersect()`.

```
if (count(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2))) {
    //at least one common value in both arrays
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, just missing a close bracket I think. `if (count(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2))) { #do stuff }`

Comment: Apologies, typo. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, loop over the array you want to check it's values and use in_array function.

Something like this:

```
<?php

    function checkCategory(): bool {
        $gated_categories = [3510, 3511];
        $category_id = [3502, 3511, 3518];
        
        foreach ($gated_categories as $cat) {
            if (in_array($cat, $category_id)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    var_dump(checkCategory());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with use from `array_diff` two times

```php
<?php
$gated_categories = [3511, 3510];
$category_id = [3518, 3511, 3502];

print_r(findGatedCategoriesContainCategoryId($gated_categories, $category_id));

function findGatedCategoriesContainCategoryId($gated_categories, $category_id) {
    $arrayDiff = array_diff($gated_categories, $category_id);
    return array_values(array_diff($gated_categories ,$arrayDiff));
}
?>
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3511
)
```

Or just use `array_intersect` like this

```php
<?php
$gated_categories = [3511, 3510];
$category_id = [3518, 3511, 3502];

$result = array_intersect($gated_categories, $category_id);
print_r($result);
?>
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3511
)
```